# Parsing HTTP GET - C

Tags: c, http, get

I'm trying to parse an HTTP GET request, and have been doing so using `strtok()`, however I am running into problems when trying to use `strcpy()`.

I can parse the file path and file name fine, but can't seem to parse the remote host DNS name. Below is code that should tokenize a string and get the DNS name, then store it in a `char[]` called `host`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int c = 0, c2 = 0;
        char *tk, *tk2, *tk3, *tk4;
        char buf[64], buf2[64], buf3[64], buf4[64];
        char host[1024], path[64], file[64];

        strcpy(buf, "GET /~yourloginid/index.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: remote.cba.csuohio.edu\r\n\r\n");

        tk = strtok(buf, "\r\n");
        while(tk != NULL)
        {
                if(c == 1)
                {
                        tk2 = strtok(tk, " ");
                        while(tk2 != NULL)
                        {
                                if(c2 == 1)
                                {
                                        printf("%s\n", tk2);
                                        strcpy(host, tk2);
                                //      printf("%s\n", host);
                                }
                                ++c2;
                                tk2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
                        }
                }
                ++c;
                tk = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Bear with me, as I'm a new C programmer and this code may be ugly. Every time I try running my program, I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error, and I believe it has something to do with `strcpy()`. I can print out the tokenized string just fine, but can't seem to copy it to a `char[]`.

Comment: It's for an assignment, and I'm pretty sure my professor wouldn't take kindly to me using something like that. Also, he wants it done in C.

Comment: `buf` can store a string of 63 characters + the null-character. This is not enough for your program requirements, and as soon as you override this array, everything else is undefined behavior.

Comment: @iharob, Even the response only has HTML in the content part of the message... not in the header. If you erase your comments I'll do the same with mine, there's no sense on maintaining them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but **strtok(3)** function is not good to parse HTTP at all.  Despite of this, I'll try to explain what's happening in your code.

1. The first time, you enter the loop with `tk=="GET /~yourloginid/index.html HTTP/1.1"`, and your buffer has been changed to `"GET /~yourloginid/index.htm HTTP/1.1\0\nHost: ..."`.  As `c==0`, you won't get into the if block, so you'll get your `c` variable incremented and `tk=strtok(NULL, "\r\n");` called again to get the second line.
2. The second time, you enter the loop with `tk=="Host: remote.cba.scuohio.edu\r\n..."`, as **strtok(3)** jumped over the first `\0` in your string, skipped all `\r` and `\n` characters, and got that  (strtok has put now a second `\0` after that part, leading to `tk=="Host: remote.cba.scuohio.edu\0\n..."`.  As `c==1` this time, you get inside the if block and call `strtok(tk, " ");`.  That makes **strtok(3)** *to forget the extent of the string you where parsing, and begin a new parse on `Host: remote.cba.csuohio.edu"`* (as you passed it a first non-null argument), it will return `tk=="Host:"`, putting a `\0` after `"host:"`.  The second time you enter the inner loop, you copy that value to `host` variable.
3. The third time you enter the main loop, you have `tk==NULL` as the last time you called `tk=strtok(NULL, " ");` it returned `NULL` (in the inner loop), strtok will continue returning `NULL` until you initialize it again, passing a first non-null argument.

**strtok(3)** operates on the string you passed as the first parameter (writing info on it) and modifies it.  Further, it has a global hidden variable to mark the end of the string you are parsing, to be able to return `NULL` when it is finished parsing.  If you nest calls to **strtok(3)** you will get undefined behaviour, as you loose the internal state of the function when you initialize it again, passing a non-null first parameter.  That is the reason of your fail.

Calling **strtok(3)** has numerous drawbacks and it cannot be nested in several nested loops as it stores internally state related to what you are parsing.  It's strongly deprecated use. If you want it to be nestable, you have to switch to **strtok_r(3)** instead.  That function has an extra parameter that allows you to save externally the strtok internal state, so you can have several strtoks working in parallel.

Further, strtok will parse ok `"GET_/~yourlogin..."` than `"GET___/~yourlogin..."`  (I have used underscores to represent spaces to show multiple spaces between method name and uri) and the latter is not permitted by HTTP.  For the same reason, you can get `"Host:remote.cba.csuohio.edu"` as a valid header field (however, this use is strongly discouraged) and you will not parse correctly that. Also, the `Host:`  header field might not be the first line in the HTTP header, so you can skip it if you are not carefull.

If you want to parse HTTP, the first reading I can recommend is the [*RFC-2616, "HyperText Transfer Protocol - HTTP/1.1"*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), which is the mandatory document to comply with for implementors.  Beware, it's a dense and large document.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the string you are trying to copy into buf is longer than the 64 chars you have allocated in the definition statement for buf.

Answer (score 0):

Trekator is right.

Replace this:

```
strcpy(buf, "GET /~yourloginid/index.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: remote.cba.csuohio.edu\r\n\r\n");
```

with:

```
char buf[] = "GET /~yourloginid/index.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: remote.cba.csuohio.edu\r\n\r\n";
```

It is good practice to use `strncpy` if there is a possibility of overrunning the destination buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

(1) You will find your life a whole lot easier if you use variable names which tell you more than 'tk2' and such.

(2) You can use `strstr()` to find the cr-nl w/o modifying the original string and it doesn't have the nesting issues that `strtok()` does.

(3) In general you can't count on Host: always being the 2nd line, so a more general approach of looking for it is more robust.

(4) Making sure things fit into their destination is "safe programming 101".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
        int     lnum    = 0;
        char buf[] = "GET /~yourloginid/index.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: remote.cba.c
suohio.edu\r\n\r\n";
        char *  line;
        char *  crnl;
        char *  colon;
        char *  arg;
        char    host[1024]      = "(not found)";

        for (line = buf;
             (crnl = strstr(line, "\r\n")) != NULL;
            line = crnl + 2) {
                ++lnum;
                if (lnum == 1) {
                        /* "GET" line is always first */
                        continue;
                }
                if (crnl == line) {             /* empty line marks end */
                        break;
                }
                if (((colon = strchr(line, ':')) == NULL) || (colon > crnl)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "no colon in header line?\n");
                        break;
                }
                if (strncasecmp(line, "Host", colon - line) == 0) {
                        for (arg = colon + 1; isspace(*arg); ++arg) {}
                        if ((crnl - arg) >= sizeof(host)) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "hostname too big\n");
                        } else {
                                strncpy(host, arg, crnl - arg);
                                host[crnl - arg] = '\0';
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("host was '%s'\n", host);
        return 0;
}
```